# Константы времени компиляции и типы в один Variadic Template

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть следующая функция:

```
template <???>
void foo();
```

Существует ли способ определить ее так, чтобы была возможность вызвать ее, например, следующим образом:

```
foo<5.0f, int, 0, double, float, 6>();
```

То есть передавать в нее как константы времени компиляции, так и типы в любом количестве и любой последовательности, и конечно же иметь ко всему этому доступ в определении функции.

Comment: Значения плавающих типов не могу выступать в качестве параметров шаблонов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Значения плавающих типов не могут выступать в качестве параметров шаблонов. В остальных случаях можно завернуть константы в тип `std::integral_constant`, т.е. свести все к типам

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename ...Args>
void foo()
{
}

int main(void)  
{
  foo<std::integral_constant<int, 5>, int, std::integral_constant<int, 0>,
    double, float, std::integral_constant<int, 6>>();    
}
```